# SPI Linux Kernel API: get struct spi_device from struct spi_controller

Tags: c, linux-device-driver, spi

How to get `struct spi_device` from `struct spi_controller`?
From **linux/spi/spi.h**, I can get `struct spi_controller` from `spi_busnum_to_master()`.

I’m not familiar with the Linux SPI system API, I cannot found suitable API here.

```c
static int __init demo_init(void)
{
        struct spi_master * spi0;
        spi0 = spi_busnum_to_master(0);
        /* I want to get spi_device from @spi0 */
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can’t. One is for the controller and another is for SPI **device** which might be connected to **this** controller (or may be not).